# Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': when importing module in Android Studio

Tags: android, module

I am trying to import another project (ExampleApp) as a library module into my current project.

I did this through File -> New -> Import Module.

I then added the dependency in the build.gradle of my main app. Here is the whole code to build.gradle of my main app:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.paigger.mainmodule"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation project(':ExampleApp')
}
```

I then made the following change  to settings.gradle

```
include ':app' , ':ExampleApp'
```

However, I get this errors:

```
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :ExampleApp.
Open File
Show Details


Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :ExampleApp.
Open File
Show Details


Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :ExampleApp.
Open File
Show Details


Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@release/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :ExampleApp.
Open File
Show Details


Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :ExampleApp.
Open File
Show Details
```

How do I fix this errors?

Comment: make sure you have submodule specified in the location specified in your gradle files and try using `api project(':ExampleApp')`

Comment: How do I add a submodule? I am a beginner to android modules.

Comment: Try this link hope this helps : [add submodue steps](https://medium.com/@deepakpk/how-to-add-a-git-android-library-project-as-a-sub-module-c713a653ab1f)

Comment: Thanks @Donny Dominic. That's a very helpful link.

Comment: Please vote :) thanks you are welcome